# Can I automatically invite a specific person to every Google Calendar meeting?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, calendar, google-calendar, sharing

I use a google account for my work calendar, but I have another Outlook exchange calendar and most of my organization uses Outlook. I know how to get my Google Calendar to show up in MY Outlook calendar list, but I can't get those items onto my Outlook calendar without 1)importing the calendar regularly (time consuming) or 2) copying each appointment over manually (time consuming).

I need the ability for my Google Calendar appointments to show up in Outlook. And the kicker is I can't install a third party app. So the only solution I've thought of is to invite myself (my Outlook account) whenever I have an appointment in my Google account.

Is there a way to automatically invite an email address to every meeting?

Comment: What specifically you need: to share Google or Outlook Calendar?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what specifically you need: to share Google or Outlook Calendar?

Maybe this will help:

> An Internet Calendar (iCal) Subscription keeps your Outlook copy of
>   your Google Calendar up-to-date.

[See your Google Calendar in Outlook](
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/See-your-Google-Calendar-in-Outlook-c1dab514-0ad4-4811-824a-7d02c5e77126)

Comment: I need to share my google calendar in outlook and ensure events from google show up on my exchange outlook calendar.

Comment: @Matt C In that case please edit question title